# Match query takes too much time in CYPHER

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working on CYPHER for different queries and my `Match` query takes too much time.

Query:

```
MATCH (a:FacebookComment), (b:FacebookLike)

WHERE a.post_id > 696
AND
a.post_id < 746 
AND 
a.id = toint(b.comment_id)

CREATE (a) <-[fpl:FB_COMMENT_LIKE]-(b)
```

There are 20117 nodes in FacebookLike and 6054 nodes in FacebookComment.

It takes 8 and half minutes to execute.

What can be issue in query or at any other point?

**EDIT**

I run **PROFILE** in cypher query

```
PROFILE 
Match (a:FacebookComment) WHERE a.post_id > 696 AND a.post_id < 746 with a
Match (b:FacebookLike) WHERE a.id = toint(b.comment_id) with b, a
MERGE (a)<-[fpl:FB_COMMENT_LIKE]-(b)
```

It took 808676 ms.

**Result:**

[image]

And Cypher query:

```
PROFILE 
Match (a:FacebookComment), (b:FacebookLike) WHERE a.id = toint(b.comment_id) AND a.post_id > 696 AND a.post_id < 746 
MERGE (a)<-[fpl:FB_COMMENT_LIKE]-(b)
```

It took 800793 ms.

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: You're building an `a` by `b` Cartesian product. You need a relationship between them, not use the WHERE clause to match on id.

Comment: Actually I am making relations between FacebookLike and FacebookComment on the base of WHERE clause.

Comment: Okay. Do you have an index on their id?

Comment: I believe the where clause is used during filtering. Your match could still be a cartesian product. You may want to EXPLAIN or PROFILE your query to see what it's doing, and then try including the relationship between the comment and the like (allowing you to remove the explicit id matching predicate in your WHERE) and see if that improves it. In general, you should be specifying desired relationships in the match, and avoiding the typical sql way of joining on ids or keys the way it is here.

Comment: I am making relations based upon WHERE clause. See my updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not be able to escape the long execution times when doing these kind of queries to create your relationships, setting up of relationships when all you have are ids and foreign keys can take time. That said, there are some great opportunities for improvement here.

Especially problematic is the toInt() you have to do on the :FacebookLike comment_id...that means that you can't take advantage of an index here. You can see that in your PROFILE, the Filter operation after the cartesian product, which does 372 million db hits; in order to do that id comparison, it must iterate over every single :FacebookLike, changing the id to an int, THEN doing the comparison. This is the most expensive part of your query.

If the :FacebookLike comment_id was already an int (that is, if toInt() isn't needed, and you left it in by mistake), or if you take some time to change every :FacebookLike comment_id to an int ahead of time, you should see a significant improvement in that filter.

That is also assuming that you create indexes on both :FacebookComment.post_id and :FacebookLike.comment_id. (also, make sure you're working with the right fields...you have post_ids, comment_ids, and ids in your query, could be easy to mix things up).

As for other improvements (AFTER you've solved the big one above), breaking up your query into multiple parts will help you avoid the cartesian product.

The full query might look like this:

```
MATCH (a:FacebookComment)
WHERE a.post_id > 696
AND a.post_id < 746 
WITH a
MATCH (b:FacebookLike)
WHERE b.comment_id = a.id
WITH a, b
CREATE (a)<-[fpl:FB_COMMENT_LIKE]-(b)
```

Comment: above query is still not valuable in case of large amount of data.
It still takes too much time to execute.

Comment: Can you run a PROFILE with the above query and add it to your description with the execution time? Along with any other factors regarding the data set you want to run this on? Is the plan to eventually run the query on the entire data set and create all of the relationships?

Comment: I tried to do so but it continue for long time and at end  `Error Undefined error Undefined error` message occur .

Comment: Okay, try with EXPLAIN instead. It won't be as detailed, but it won't need to do a full execution.

Comment: Thanks for your response
Issue was that I changed query a little bit.
I used `Return` instead of `CREATE` relation, so it was taking too much time to return data.

Comment: That could do it. Keep in mind that the point of the above query is to create the relationships. That takes a bit, but it should be a one-time thing. After these relationships are in place, you should be using those relationships (instead of the WHERE match on the ids) in your other queries instead. That should speed them up significantly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117998/discussion-between-usman-maqbool-and-inversefalcon).